# How To Change Font Bold in Crystal Report In C#

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I'm facing problem a with Crystal report. I want to display location like

```
J1 // One by one
J3
```

in data table. Then I want check condition like if J3 and OT='YES' (OT column from datatbase), if true means I want show J3 as bold.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the field that displays the `J1`, `J3` and click on Format Object to enter the Format Editor.

In the font tab you can find the `Style` property as shown below:

[image]

Click on the [x+2] button which is on the right side of the style property and write the following code there

```
if {DataTable1.ColumnName} = "J3" and {DataTable1.OT} = "YES" then
    crBold
else
    crRegular
```

*Replace the* `DataTable1` *with the name of your data source and the* `ColumnName` *with the name of the field that holds the* `J1`, `J3`.